# AngularJS - display username and image with firebase and GoogleAuth

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to create a profile page that displays username and image. 
But for now I have been struggling with Username.

Profile page that display username and image but for now username with googAuth.

Is there anyone who knows how to do it?

```
$scope.login = function()
{
 var ref = new          Firebase("https://fire.firebaseio.com");
      var authData = ref.getAuth();

      var userId = authData.uid;
      var name = authData[authData.provider].displayName;

     ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData)
     {
      $timeout(function() {

         $scope.username = name;
         $scope.userid = userId;
          console.log( $scope.username );
          console.log( $scope.userid );

      });



     if (error)
      {
             console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      }
     else
     {

        $state.go('tabsController.pendingTasks');
        ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).once("value",function(snapshot)
        {
         var ifExists = snapshot.exists();

          if(ifExists)
           {
              console.log("user already exists");
           }
           else
            {
              ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).push({id:userId,name:name
            }

            );
          }
        });

      }
  },
  {remember: "sessionOnly",
      scope: "email"});
}

})
```

This seems not to work because the username doesn't show up in my ionic view. The HTML part is as below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js</script>
<ion-view title="Reminders" id="page7">
 <ion-content padding="true" ng-controller="loginCtrl" class="hasheader">
   <div class="list card">
     <div class="item item-divider">{{username}}</span></div>
        <div class="item item-body">
            <form class="list">
                <ion-checkbox>{{username}}</ion-checkbox>
             </form>
             </div>
            </div>

        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If I am getting this correct, You want to create a profile for a user as soon as they create an account ?

Comment: could firebase security & rules prevent me from making this info public on my app profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking up the user name when it isn't available yet. This will work better:

```
var userId;
var name;

ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData)
{
    userId = authData.uid;
    name = authData[authData.provider].displayName;
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.username = name;
        $scope.userid = userId;
        console.log( $scope.username );
        console.log( $scope.userid );
    });
}
```

Comment: this ddnt work i dont know if there's something wrong im doing or there's permissions im not including because this doesn't bind still

Comment: This fixes a mistake in your original code. If it's not enough, consider setting up a minimal jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces your problem. Stack Overflow is a lousy tool for helping you debug non-trivial code.